# php mail() - one work, one don't

Tags: php, email

I have created a big input form, with about 250 variables. These get transfered via POST. I can echo these variables with php on the site, where the mail should be send.

On another site I have the same script, but in a much shorter way. This script sends me emails, but the other one, the big one doesn't.

Are there any restrictions to the mail() function?

The working script is

```
mail($Email, $subject, $nachricht, 'From noreply@xxx.de');
```

The script, which fails is

```
mail($mail, $subject, $nachricht, 'From xxx@xxx.de');
```

So if I look at the code, I can't find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because maybe: `$mail` does not exist or is empty and `$Email` does.

If it can't deliver, you will get a `false` as a response.

Note: The header should be `From: xxx@xxx.de`?

Comment: $mail is defined by $mail = 'xxx@xxx.de'; - The xxx are placeholders ( in my script there is a real email ;) )